# Problem with new dimmer. Starts to dim after 90 degrees. How to fix?

Tags: dimmer-switch

I installed a new dimmer (Nordlux SD600) in my hallway because the old one was broken.
Here's the [documentation](https://www.megaflis.no/globalassets/productimages/7057385315567_manual.pdf), its not much there, i.e there seems to be no screws or anything to configure the dimmer.

When the dimmer is on and i turn it the clockwise direction to make it brighter, it doesn't get bright until i have turned it 90 degrees, then it starts to dim brighter. Then there is 45 degrees left. So when ive reached that 90 to 135 degree area it turns bright, but this happens so fast. I want to be able to dim the light slower: 0 to 135 degrees.

I have no experience with dimmers before, so I wonder what can be done to fix this?
I want to be able to turn the lights brighter but not 90 to 135.. I hope I was able to explain it clearly. So anyone knows how I can fix this? I dont want to buy a new dimmer again, because this is just brand new.

Comment: What kind of lights is it controlling? How many watts total?

Comment: @Ecnerwal LED lights,  12W/555lm.

Comment: this is the ceiling light: https://www.bohus.no/belysning-1/lamper/taklamper/anillo-takplafond-1

Comment: hm. strange.. now the dimmer dont work at all... or the lights.

Comment: i think that dimmer is for low-voltage lighting, which i can't tell whether or not the fixture is.